# Route to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller called Admin with a number of Actions.  In the URL, they look like this:

http://www.website.com/Admin/Users/1

http://www.website.com/Admin/Roles/123

Is there anyway to alias out so that:

http://www.website.com/Users/1

http://www.website.com/Roles/123

Automatically goes to the right controller?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without interfering with the default route, unless you are not going to use the names `Users` or `Roles` anywhere else. If that is the case, you can just add

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminUsers",
    "Users/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Users", id = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminRoles",
    "Roles/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Roles", id = "" });
```

to your `Global.asax.cs` file.